# Bitbucket Markdown substitute for HTML comment tag

Tags: markdown, bitbucket

In Github Markdown HTML tags are supported, so one can comment out lines using standard `<!--foo-->` HTML. Bitbucket does not support HTML inside rendered Markdown. Is there an alternative way to comment out lines on Bitbucket? I have checked the docs but have had no luck. Also, since comment is a word that is used outside my intended context using searching tools have been unfruitful.

Comment: Since your using a version control system, why do you need to comment out lines? Just remove them. If you need to remember what was there before, just check the commit history.

Comment: My point is that it is entirely possible that Bitbucket sees no need to offer a comment feature. Markdown certainly does not have such a feature outside of raw HTML.

Comment: This lack of HTML support is a big nuisance. I normally add a color palette and screenshots to my `README.md` files. I can't with Bitbucket. Makes me really want to move to Github Entreprise.